# Which one of "firing", "shooting", "gunfire", and "fire" is best in the context?

Tags: word-choice

> Two soldiers with machine guns opened fire at Tarik. Tarik took cover. After a while, the firing/shooting/gunfire/fire stopped.

Which one would be the best in this context? Gunfire? Would they all be OK?

Comment: Any of "firing," "shooting," or "gunfire" are idiomatic and appropriate. "Fire" is not because "fire" as a noun has a different meaning than "gunfire."

Comment: "Fire" could be misunderstood here, but probably everybody would guess the intended meaning, in the given context. Supplementing Jeff Morrow's comment by saying that "open fire" (as a verb) and "cease fire" (a verb or a noun) do have meanings where "fire" refers to "gunfire" in particular. I think "Fire" is also used as an order in military contexts, and obviously refers to gunfire (from guns of unspecified nature - applies to both infantry and artillery).

Comment: See [meaning 5A in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fire).

Comment: "the barrage ended"